# How to align numbers in table to the left?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/6a7d2snj/

I want to align all numbers to the left side inside a table column:

```
 50
  5
-40
 -4
```

But how? `style="align:right"` would give me the correct alignment on the right, but I want this on the left!

Comment: Try left then? align:left

Comment: This is not possible with text alignment without additional wrapping elements with specific widths. There is no CSS method of aligning elements/text that do not share a parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D could you give an example with wrapping elements? I'd be happy with any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with text alignment without additional wrapping elements with specific widths.

**There is no CSS method of aligning elements/text that do not share a parent.**

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4ch;
  text-align: right;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td><span>5</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><span>50</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td><span>-50</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><span>-4</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```